# PHP Array get all possible variations from multiply arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

here is already some posts like this but non of them helped me,
I have example array that looks like this

```
$array = array(
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-1',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '2',
    'required' => '1'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-2',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '12',
    'required' => '1'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-3',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '132',
    'required' => '1'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 2-1',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '2',
    'selectionId' => '11',
    'required' => '0'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 2-2',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '14',
    'required' => '0'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 2-3',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '2',
    'selectionId' => '12',
    'required' => '0'
),
```

);

And output should be like

```
array (
array (
'label' => "test 1-1 + test 2-1",
'price-value' => '20',
'required' => '1'
)
)
```

and so on...
but with out any duplicates like test 2-1 + test 1-1 will be duplicate
arrays are grouped 'attr_id' and there can be 100's like
Sesction_id is this element id their will not be same section ids in one attr_id but they can be same if attr_id is not same.. Hope it make sense.

also if required is set to 0 then their should be 2options with this and without it

like "required1 + required2 + not required3" and "required1 + required2"

I'm really bad in sorting arrays can somebody help me with this ?

edit :

all this options is from two arrays merged in to one
each array id is in attr_id so there can not be same objects in one variation like there can not be test 1-1 + test 1-2

Code need to output all possible variations 
in this example it will be like

```
test 1-1 + test 2-1 |
test 1-1 + test 2-2 |
test 1-1 + test 2-3 |

test 1-2 + test 2-1 |
test 1-2 + test 2-2 |
test 1-2 + test 2-3 |

test 1-3 + test 2-1 |
test 1-3 + test 2-2 |
test 1-3 + test 2-3 |

$array = array(
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-1 + test 2-1',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-1 + test 2-2',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-1 + test 2-3',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),

array(
    'label' => 'test 1-2 + test 2-1',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-2 + test 2-2',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-2 + test 2-3',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-3 + test 2-1',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-3 + test 2-2',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-3 + test 2-3',
    'pricing_value' => '20'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-1',
    'pricing_value' => '10'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-2',
    'pricing_value' => '10'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-3',
    'pricing_value' => '10'
),
```

);

and also there need to be just test-1 all elements because test-2 is not required

```
test 1-1 |
test 1-2 |
test 1-3 |
```

Hope it will help

Comment: you want to filter this array by attr_id?  is it??

Comment: In this example there are two changeable options and they id is in attr_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and let me know if this is what you want:

```
        <?php 
$array = array(
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-1',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '2',
    'required' => '1'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-2',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '12',
    'required' => '1'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 1-3',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '132',
    'required' => '1'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 2-1',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '2',
    'selectionId' => '11',
    'required' => '0'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 2-2',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '1',
    'selectionId' => '14',
    'required' => '0'
),
array(
    'label' => 'test 2-3',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '2',
    'selectionId' => '12',
    'required' => '0'
)
);

$filteredArray=array();
$count=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $filteredArray[$value['required']][$count]['label']=$value['label'];
        $filteredArray[$value['required']][$count]['pricing_value']=$value['pricing_value'];
        $count++;
}

$finalArray=array();
foreach($filteredArray[1] as $key=>$value){
    if(!isset($finalArray[$value['label']])){
        $finalArray[$value['label']]=$value['pricing_value'];
    }
    foreach($filteredArray[0] as $key=>$value1){
        if(!isset($finalArray[$value['label']."+".$value1['label']])){
            $finalArray[$value['label']."+".$value1['label']]=$value['pricing_value']+$value1['pricing_value'];
        }
    }
}
print_r($finalArray);die;
?>
```

Output:

```
   Array
(
    [test 1-1] => 10
    [test 1-1+test 2-1] => 20
    [test 1-1+test 2-2] => 20
    [test 1-1+test 2-3] => 20
    [test 1-2] => 10
    [test 1-2+test 2-1] => 20
    [test 1-2+test 2-2] => 20
    [test 1-2+test 2-3] => 20
    [test 1-3] => 10
    [test 1-3+test 2-1] => 20
    [test 1-3+test 2-2] => 20
    [test 1-3+test 2-3] => 20
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, output should be all possible variations but only with two elements because their is only two different attribute id so their can not be variation where both elements is with same attr_id.
in this case their should be like 
test 1-1 + test 2-1 |
test 1-1 + test 2-2 |
test 1-1 + test 2-3 |

test 1-2 + test 2-1 |
test 1-2 + test 2-2 |
test 1-2 + test 2-3 |

test 1-3 + test 2-1 |
test 1-3 + test 2-2 |
test 1-3 + test 2-3 |

test 1-1 |
test 1-2 |
test 1-3 |

Comment: Actually your requirement is not clear.. Thats why m not able to help you. Make your requirement more understandable.

Comment: Can you please tell me exact desired output using above array?

Comment: Thanks @Maverick, we are almost there, but If we add one more option array
like 
array(
    'label' => 'test 3-1',
    'pricing_value' => '10',
    'attr_id' => '3',
    'selectionId' => '132',
    'required' => '1'
),
With attr_id 3 it need to also add test 1-3+test 2-3 + test 3-1 .... and if it's not required then all posible variations with out it and there can be like 100's of this variatons if their is more then 3 attributes

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: This was not solution for me but it helped me to find solution, thanks @Maverick